# A finite supersolvable group with generators of prescribed order

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=\langle a,b\rangle$ be a finite supersolvable group. Is there any special information about the structure of $G$ when $o(a)=2$ and $ o(b)=2^k > 2$?

Comment: Usually, two-generators groups are well-suited for being represented on a surface. You may look for keywords like "hyperbolic groups" or "Fuchsian group". You use the Cayley graph and the natural action of the group on it (see, e.g., http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895683900096 ). In the most cases, the group is infinite (see the Burnside problem).